# Match too long lines inside Python comment block in vim

Tags: vim, vim-syntax-highlighting

I need to highlight extra characters of too long Python docstring lines

Trying to use this code:

```
syn region PythonDocString  start=+^\s*[uU]\?[rR]\?"""+ end=+"""+ keepend excludenl
syn match TooLongDocString /\%80v.*/ containedin=PythonDocString
hi TooLongDocString guifg=Red
```

But it matches lines outside docstrings too and turns off the default Python comments highlighting. How to make it work?

**UPDATE**

before
[image]
after
[image]

**UPDATE 2**

Suddenly, for a file without any comments of the form `"""` I get:

[image]

The line:

```
        sha = subprocess.check_output(['git', 'rev-parse', 'HEAD'], cwd=cwd).decode('ascii').strip()
```

Current code:

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.py syn region pythonDocString  start=+^\s*[uU]\?[rR]\?"""+ end=+"""+ keepend excludenl contains=pythonEscape,@Spell,pythonDoctest,pythonDocTest2,pythonSpaceError,pythonDocstringTooLong
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.py syn match pythonDocStringTooLong /\%81v.*/ contained
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.py hi def link pythonDocString pythonString
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.py hi def link pythonDocStringTooLong Error
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `containedin=...` adds the current syntax element to the contained list of the referenced one, but **it does imply `contained`**. Without that attribute on `TooLongDocString` (which BTW should also have the `python...` prefix for consistency), that element will match *anywhere*.

In any case, as you have control over both definitions, you can just use `contains=pythonDocstringTooLong` on `pythonDocstring`. I also think there are other (default) syntax elements that should be contained:

```
syn region pythonDocString  start=+^\s*[uU]\?[rR]\?"""+ end=+"""+ keepend excludenl contains=pythonEscape,@Spell,pythonDoctest,pythonDocTest2,pythonSpaceError,pythonDocstringTooLong
syn match pythonDocStringTooLong /\%80v.*/ contained
```

`containedin=` usually is used when you cannot modify the referenced syntax element definition.

Finally, I would link to an existing highlight group instead of defining a (GUI-only) highlighting:

```
hi def link pythonDocStringTooLong Error
```

Comment: Great! It almost works. This code still cancels default Python formatting for docstrings. Maybe the problem is that I use this code only for specific project, on load. So it is not in any syntax file.

Comment: Are you looking for `hi def link pythonDocString pythonComment`?

Comment: No, I mean that when I use this code, all docstrings change their color to default black, but they were green before.

Comment: I've added pictures

Comment: Yeah, unless you assign a _highlight group_ to the new `pythonDocString`, it will be default black. That's why my command links this to `pythonComment`, which (at least for me) is the default comment coloring (green).

Comment: Put the commands into `~/.vim/after/syntax/python.vim`; don't use those `:autocmd`s! Also, please avoid any further back and forth. If you have a different issue, rather open a new question, and accept the current one, so that it is kept focused on a single issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147465/discussion-between-leonidas-and-ingo-karkat).